# Finding "all" domains of a country

Tags: web-crawler, tld

I'm searching a way to find "all" the sites ending with an given tld. I had several ideas on how to realize that, but I'm not sure what is the best/most effectiv way to realize this. I'm aware that pages that are linked nowhere aren't findable by spiders etc, so fir this example I'll not care about isolated pages.
What I want to do, I want to have an TLD as input for my programm, and I which to have a list of sites as output. For example:

```
# <program> .de
- spiegel.de
- deutsche-bank.de
...
- bild.de
```

So what is the best way to reach this? Are there tools available to help me, or how would you program this?

Comment: Sure? DNS Zone transfer could give you the list if and only if you are authorized to do a AXFR  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_zone_transfer

Comment: Hello Rene, thx for your answer. I did some research on your post and I'm able to perform such AXFR queries for one domain, now I'm unsure how I would do it for an entire TLD, I used dig for my tests. Are there better tools?

Comment: AFAIK the DNS servers in the wild don't allow AXFR commands for non-authorative servers, which you and I probably have. If such a tool exist dig should be up to the task.

Answer (score 8):

*This answer might be a bit late but I've just found this.*

You could try using **Common Crawler** awesome data.

So, **what is Common Crawler?**

> Common Crawl is a 501(c)(3) non-profit organization dedicated to
>   providing a copy of the internet to internet researchers, companies
>   and individuals at no cost for the purpose of research and analysis.

Using their [url search tool](http://urlsearch.commoncrawl.org/) query for `.de` then download the result as a `json` file.

You will get a nice file of results then you will need to do some work on it since it includes all the site map of a domain (hence crawling).

Another drawback that some sites use unwelcoming `robot.txt` file so crawlers won't be included them still it's the best result i could find so far.

Comment: It seems like their data is not updated often. For `.by` domain the results contain only pages prior to Mar 2012.

Answer (score 1):

The code bellow is a multithreaded domain checker script in python3 that uses something like a brute-force string generator that is appended to a list and that list has all the possible combinations (depending on the length that is specified)of chars maybe you need to add some characters to it. I successfully used it for Chinese, Russian, Dutch sites.

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
from urllib.request import urlopen
import pandas as pd

from itertools import product

chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890' # add all chars in your language
urls = []# list
for length in range(0, 9999): # Change this length 
    to_attempt = product(chars, repeat=length)
    for attempt in to_attempt:
        a=("https://"+''.join(attempt)+".de")
        urls.append(a)


import sys
sys.stdout = open('de.csv','wt')
def fetch_url(url):
    try:
        response = urlopen(url)
        return url, response.read(), None
    except Exception as e:
        return url, None, e

start = timer()
results = ThreadPool(4000).imap_unordered(fetch_url, urls)
for url, html, error in results:
    if error is None:
        print(url)
```

Comment: Good idea. One can try also a dictionary, used for passwords crackers.

Comment: This code fills up memory while generating the links. I was not able to use it.